# What is the alternative for Mongo Connector?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, elasticsearch

I want to use Elasticsearch using MongoDB, yet I can't find a good, well-maintained connector library. River-MongoDB is outdated, mongo-connector is outdated. Mongoosastic is not eligible for my system. I've tried Monstache but didn't work for me.

Are there any supported npm packages from Mongo or Elastic.co?

Comment: We've ended up with using Logstash for now. But still open for recommendations.

Comment: not from mongo but we use a nom package called `etl` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/etl) which can be easily used to stream data from either direction. Mongo to elastic or vice versa. You could also do your custom transformation if you like.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library [monstache](https://github.com/rwynn/monstache)

a very awesome library with advanced features.